# Problem retrieving KnowledgeArticleVersion records using Remote Objects

Tags: javascript-remoting, remote-objects

I have been experimenting with Javascript remote objects, trying to retrieve a list of knowledge articles by creating a remote object on the KnowledgeArticleVersion object. My visualforce component definition is:

```
<apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="RemoteObjectModel">
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="KnowledgeArticleVersion">
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="KnowledgeArticleId" />
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="ArticleType" />
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="Title" />
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="Summary" />
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="LastPublishedDate" />
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="PublishStatus" />
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="Language" />
    </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

I have only one Knowledge article in my organization and its Id is: 'ka0o0000000E5lIAAS'

However, in the javascript RemoteObjectModel.retrieve method where I attempt to retrieve the KnowledgeArticleVersion records, I am getting an error:

**Uncaught Error: Invalid id provided: ka0o0000000E5lIAAS Expected value with prefix: ka# and length 15 or 18**

The error is occurring in the VFSObjectCRUD.js file that Salesforce automatically includes when declaring your remote object components in the visualforce. It appears that what is causing the retrieval to fail is that the prefix 'a' (ka#) is not equal to what is in the first three characters of the string 'b' (ka0) as you can see from the debugging screenshot below:

[image]

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong here or if this is some sort of known bug or limitation with the usage of Knowledge and remote objects

Comment: The work around that I've been using is to retrieve the article types instead, though that is really not ideal since that retrieves all custom field data as well.